# Extract number from string

Tags: 12.04, command-line, scripts

When using this ubuntu command:

```
${HOME}/temp/.git describe --always --tags HEAD
```

the output of this command is:

```
v0.1.5-2-p343h3d3
```

I want to extract `1.5` from the output above and check if it's greater than 1.5 or not.
Is there any solution for this.?

Comment: Why not `0.1.5`? The `0` seems relevant...

Comment: @Oli                                                               I just want to check 0.1.5 is greater than 0.1.5 or not. inclusion of 0 is not matter for me.

Comment: What about in the future when it might return something like ***`"v1.1.0-3-p343h3d3"`*** OR ***`"v2.0.7-4-p343h3d3"`*** OR ***`"v10.0.9-5-p343h3d3"`***? If you ignore the "leading" number (the digit 0 from ***`"v0"`*** in your example), these will look like ***`"1.0"`***, ***`"0.7"`***, and ***`"0.9"`***, so these will all fail your test, even though you will probably want them all to pass your test of being **`">=1.5"`**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like

```
${HOME}/temp/.git describe --always --tags HEAD  | awk ' {
                             match ($0, /[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/,m)
                             if(m[0]>"0.1.5"){ 
                                 print("hello")
                              }
                             }'
```

This will check the first matching regex result. Just throwing another way to do this, although I'm not sure how much of a practical way this is for you.

Cheers

Comment: Warning on string comparison:  Version `0.1.33` is considered a "lower" version here

Comment: It's an interesting angle but it's not numeric enough to work. `echo | awk '{if("0.1.10">"0.1.5"){ print "oh hai" }}'`

Comment: Of course, numeric comparison on string is not recommended. This is like a quick hack.

Answer (score 5):

Version numbers are actually pretty tough to compare given that they're often not standard mathematical comparisons (this one for instance has two decimal points that makes `bc` throw up).

Therefore I turn to a lesser-known option in `sort` that can be used to sort version strings. Consider the following:

```
$ echo -e "v0.1.5\nv0.1.6-2-p343h3d3" | sort -V
v0.1.5
v0.1.6-2-p343h3d3

oli@bert:~$ echo -e "v0.1.5\nv0.1.4-2-p343h3d3" | sort -V
v0.1.4-2-p343h3d3
v0.1.5
```

This basically means we can sort the versions so the latest is on the last line. All we have to do then is a string comparison against the last line, inside an `if`, or a shortcutted-if:

```
[[ $(echo -e "v0.1.5\nv0.1.4-2-p343h3d3" | sort -V | tail -1) != "v0.1.5" ]] && echo NEWER
```

Play around with the `v0.1.4-2-p343h3d3` string. If you stick it up to `0.1.6` it'll echo out.

Now to bring this all back around to your command:

```
[[ $(echo -e "v0.1.5\n$(${HOME}/temp/.git describe --always --tags HEAD)" | sort -V | tail -1) != "v0.1.5" ]] && echo NEWER
```

Or you could break it down for readability:

```
THRESHOLD="v0.1.5"
VERSION=$(${HOME}/temp/.git describe --always --tags HEAD)
if [[ $(echo -e "$THRESHOLD\n$VERSION" | sort -V | tail -1) != "$THRESHOLD"  ]]; then
    echo GREATER
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following command to `exit` with a `0` status if the version extracted is greater than 1.5

```
${HOME}/temp/.git describe --always --tags HEAD | perl -ne '/v\d+\.(\d+\.\d+)/;exit(1) if $1 <= 1.5'
```

Comment: Updated to match your new version pattern